# Expression Engine Member Import XML Custom Fields

Tags: xml, import, expressionengine, custom-fields

I have an Excel document containing the details of 2000 users that need to be imported as Members in Expression Engine - using the Member Import utility.

Where on earth do I start?

**First Problem**
- converting the Excel doc into XML format.

**Second Problem** - including over 60 custom member fields.

**Third Problem** - ensuring each user has a unique username, screen_name, password, salt, unique_id and crypt_key.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in out.

> First Problem - converting the Excel doc into XML format.

Create an XML Schema, then in Excel > Developer tab > Source > XML Maps > Drag and Drop Map for A:1, copy and paste tab delimated data into A:2

> Second Problem - including over 60 custom member fields.

In EE, if you simply leave the 'Create custom fields' unchecked - all custom member field/XML tags will insert correspondingly.

> Third Problem - ensuring each user has a unique username, screen_name, password, salt, unique_id and crypt_key.

Use this - http://dosysadminsdream.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/generating-random-passwords-in-excel/ - to create a module in Excel VB for the passwords. Ensure your XML has type='text' attribute in the password tag, EE will do the MD5 on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest bypassing the Member Import Utility and writing a custom PHP script that writes directly to the database.  You can export your Excel doc to CSV and use something like [parsecsv](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/) to parse it into a PHP array.

Just setup all of your custom member fields first, add few sample members manually, and then inspect the exp_member_* database tables to see how the data is arranged. You can base your script INSERTS off of that.

If you write this custom script as an EE module or plugin (or simply as a PHP-enabled template), you can bypass setting up database connections and use the [Database class](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/database.html) for your inserts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with commercial addons, you can use a combination of [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) and Andrew Weaver's [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) to accomplish this. First, set up Zoo Visitor, and create fields in the Zoo Visitor channel for all the data you want to import. Then use DataGrab to import your records into the channel. Since Zoo Visitor automatically creates members when an entry is created in its channel, you'll get members as well as channel entries when you run the import.

If it's a one-time thing, and you want all the data to be in Member Fields (instead of in Channel Fields, which is what ZV does), you can easily do a few extra steps. Create the Member Fields you want, run a quick query directly against the database to UPDATE all the Member Fields from the corresponding Channel Fields, and then kill the channel and uninstall Zoo Visitor and DataGrab. (If the import is going to be a regular thing, I'd advise skipping this part and leaving things in Zoo Visitor and channels instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor) to manage your member, and import with [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab).